# Example of a set which is not compact.

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that the clopen interval $[0,1)$ is not compact.

For this, I have taken the open cover ${[1/n,1)}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. How can I show that this open cover has no finite subcover?

Comment: Your sets are not open, nor do they cover the set $[0, 1)$ (specifically, $0$ is not in any of the sets). You're on the right track though! Just tweak your intervals.

Comment: I think you can take the collection {[1/n, 1-1/n):n>2} as a cover for [0,1)

Comment: @Jasmine Both problems in the above comment also apply to your cover

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. @stewen's question i also have the querry about the set (0,1]. Can i take the collection {(1/n, 1] : n=1,2,,3...}as an open cover which has no finite subcover

Comment: Since your are new. When someone give you an answer and that you think that the answer is good and correct you can can approve the question to give some credit to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your proposal, $0 \notin [\frac1n, 1)$, so we don't have a cover, and the sets are not open in $[0,1)$ as $\frac1n$ is not an interior point.

The problem lies on the $1$-side: take $U_n = [0, 1 - \frac{1}{n+1})$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. This *is* an open cover: if $0 \le x < 1$ pick $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1} < 1-x$ and then $x \in [0,1-\frac{1}{n+1})$.

If $U_{n_1}, \ldots, U_{n_k}$ is a finite subfamily, then all $U_{n_i}$ are subsets of the one belonging to the highest $n$, so their union is just $U_{n_j}$ for $n_j = \max(n_1, \ldots, n_k)$ but then you don't cover the elements in $[1-\frac{1}{n_j+1}, 1)$, so a finite subfamily is never a subcover.

Answer (score 0):

Your cover just needs to be tweaked.

Consider the cover $[0,1-1/n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}, n\neq1}$

Note that these are open in the subspace topology on $[0,1)$.

(Exercise : Check that it is indeed a cover.)

Let the finite subcover be $[0,1-1/n_i)_{i=1.....k}$.

Choose $j$ such that $1-1/n_j$ is maximum of all $(1-1/n_i)$'s.

Then pick a real number between $1$ and $1-1/n_j$. Does it lie in the above subcover?.

Comment: $0$ is in none of your sets.

Comment: I have edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{R}$ (or in a metric space )( in   $\mathbb{R}$  there is. a more strong theorem Heine Borel ) :

Compact $\Rightarrow $ closed:  but [0,1) is not closed since $1-1/n$ is in the set but converge to 1 that is not in the set .

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is Hausdorff so any compact set is also closed. The proof that compact sets are closed in Hausdorff spaces is not difficult either.